# Global variables in arrow function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to REACT so please correct me if I am wrong. When defining hooks, I can use the property all over my arrow function. Something like:

```
const CrawlJobs = () => {
   const [crawlList, setCrawlList] = useState([]);
};
```

Everything OK here. As far as I understand the hooks in REACT is used because the render content know when data has changed and can update the DOM. But what if I have some simple properties/variables that is not used in the UI. Should I still define global variables as hooks? I tried defining a variable like this:

```
const statusId = 0;
```

However this could not be used globally in my arrow function component and doing below gave an error:

```
const this.statusId = 0;
```

So my question is should I always define all properties as hooks, or is there away to just define variables as standard variables in REACT? I dont want to define hooks if it is not needed.

Comment: You don't always have to use hook if it doesn't need to change its value during render. Just use const or let. And you can't use "this" is a functional component. If you want to redefine the value of statusId, just write statusId=your value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a function to use **useState** so the correction:

```
const [crawlList, setCrawlList] = useState([]);
```

And functional component don't need ***this***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your variables in the state as long as they are not affecting the application UI, component state usually used to notify the UI that there is a state it cares about changed, then the component itself should react to the change based on the state. the following is a silly example, just to demonstrate:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const label = 'You clicked';
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{label} {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So its totally fine to have variables without binding them to state.

Comment: Thanks very helpfull. It got me a little further. I could reproduce your point in this sample with success. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chaum-5iqmj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. However in my real app it did not work. And I have realized by adding an alert where i define my variable alert(filterStatusId);
  let filterStatusId = 0; that my component often are intialized again, and that was the problem. So my variable keeps getting initialized. If i put it in the constructor (useState) then it is not defined. And to be honest I dont know why my function app gets initialized.

Comment: It is kind of strange it gets initialized as it is the top component.